# Validation of specific attribute rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, model

I have a trouble validating one form, I have a Product model with several attributes, but I would like to make a method for validate the presence of almost one attribute of the following:

Product.rb

```
   attr_accessible :ship_int, ship_df, :tipo_envio

  #I'm trying to validate :ship_df like this:

validates :ship_df, :presence => { :message => "*seleciona al menos una opcion de envio"}, 
:allow_blank => true, :on => :create, :if => :almost_one_option_df?

 def almost_one_option_df?
    ship_df != nil || tipo_envio != nil || ship_int != nil
 end
```

The question is, how can I validate the presence of almost one of those three attributes?, if one is presence the Product can be created.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to validate that at least one of `ship_df`, `tipo_envio` or `ship_int` is set?  If one, or two, or three of them have a value it is valid, but if none of the have a value it is not?

If so, I'd check for `blank` not `nil`:

```
validate :any_present?

def any_present?
  if %w(ship_df tipo_envio ship_int).all?{|attr| self[attr].blank?}
    errors.add :base, "*seleciona al menos una opcion de envio"
  end
end
```

Comment: I've tried your method, but I have one error log, undefined method `add_to_base', what do you think?